# How to get sum of all items?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get sum of all items of cars. But i'm just getting sum of each items, which you can see here [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMBOB.png)

So how can I get sum of all items, like the sum is (4), instead of getting each items?

*Controller:*

```
     public ActionResult Home()
        {
            var model = new CompositeModel();

            model.CountCars = getCountOfCars();

            return View(model);
        }
  private IEnumerable<CountCarsrCountView> getCountOfCars()
        {
            var countCars = this.Data.Cars.All()
                    .Select(t => new CountCarsrCountView
                    {
                        counter = t.Cars.Count()
                    });   
            return countCars ;
        }
```

*ViewModel*

```
public class CountCarsViewModel
{
    public int counter { get; set; }
}
```

*CompositeModel*

```
public class CompositeModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<CountCarsViewModel> CountCars { get; set; }
    }
```

*View*

```
@model  CompositeModel

<div class="container">

  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.CountCarsViewModel.Count(); i++)
  {
      var cars = Model.CountCarsViewModel.ElementAt(i);     
      <p>@cars.counter</p>
  }
</div>
```

Car model:

```
     public class Car
    {
      [Key]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Title { get; set; }
      public string Description { get; set; }
      public int Price { get; set; }

      public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
      public int CategoryId { get; set; }

      public int FilePathId { get; set; }
      public string FileName { get; set; }
      public string UserId { get; set; }
      public virtual User Users { get; set; }
     }
```

Comment: It's really unclear what do you want to sum... What's more, you seem to use `All()` with no reason.

Comment: What is the property of your model that you want to sum?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to get sum of Car model.

Comment: Do you mean you want the sum of the `Price` property for all cars in the collection? (your current code does not make sense so its unclear what your trying to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq as so:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public int MyCount { get; set; }
}

public List<MyItem> AllItems { get; set; }
```

In this example if you want the count of all items in the list you would do this:

```
var count = AllItems.Count();
```

If you wanted to sum the Counts of all items in the list you would do this:

```
  var count2 = AllItems.Sum(a => a.MyCount);
```

Example:

```
AllItems = new List<UserQuery.MyItem>()
{
    new MyItem(){ MyCount = 3 },
    new MyItem(){ MyCount = 4 },
};

var count = AllItems.Count(); // This would be 2
var count2 = AllItems.Sum(a => a.MyCount); // This would be 7
```